# Ant:build.xml; XML document structure must start and end within the same entity

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have the following directory structure

```
+project
    +--profile
         +---src
         +---WebContent
         +---build
```

I am trying to compile and copy using Ant, but when I execute the following **build.xml** file I get this error **XML document structure must start and end within the same entity** and nothing else. I checked a couple of almost similar questions but none of them helped, the only question similar to this was collected by adding any thing within  like a comment which didn't work for me. What am I missing in the build file?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="profile" basedir="." default="Task-of-build">
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="webcontent.dir" value="WebContent"/>
<property name="javadoc" value="doc"/>
<property name="name" value="profile"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${webcontent.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<property name="backup.dir" value="C:/project/backup"/>

<path id="classpathvalue">
    <fileset dir="${webcontent.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    <!-- this is a comment -->
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="javadoc">
    <javadoc packagenames="com.mucyo.prep.profile.*" sourcepath="${src.dir}"
        destdir = "doc" version="true" windowtitle="Profile Mngt">
       <doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>=Profile Mgnt =</h1>]]</doctitle>
       <bottom><![CDATA[Copyright 2011. All Rights reserved></bottom>
       <group title="Beans packages" packages="com.mucyo.prep.profile.bean.*"/>
       <group title="Service packages" pachages="com.mucyo.prep.profile.services.*"/>
       <group title="servlets packages" packages="com.mucyo.profile.servlets.*"/>
    </javadoc>
</target>
<target name="Task-of-build">
    <echo message="This a build example"/>
</target>
<target name="build" description="compiling java files">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="true"
       deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
          <src path="${src.dir}"/>
          <classpath refid="classpathvalue"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="create-war" depends="build">
    <war destfile="${name}.war" webxml="${webcontent.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
       <fileset dir=".">
          <include name="**/*.*"/>
       </fileset>
    </war>
</target>
<target name="backup" depends="build">
    <mkdir dir="${backup.dir}"/>
    <copy todir="${backup.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
       <fileset dir=".">
          <include dir="${src.dir}:${build.dir}"/>
       </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean" depends="build">
    <delete>
       <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
          <include name="**/*.class"/>
       </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

```
<doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>=Profile Mgnt =</h1>]]</doctitle>
<bottom><![CDATA[Copyright 2011. All Rights reserved></bottom>
```

Neither of your CDATA sections are properly terminated, so your file is simply not valid XML. I think you should have:

```
<doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>=Profile Mgnt =</h1>]]></doctitle>
<bottom><![CDATA[Copyright 2011. All Rights reserved>]]></bottom>
```

... although as the second of these strings does anything which requires escaping in XML, I woudln't even use a CDATA section for it:

```
<doctitle><![CDATA[<h1>=Profile Mgnt =</h1>]]></doctitle>
<bottom>Copyright 2011. All Rights reserved></bottom>
```

... and even the first one just needs the open angle brackets escaping:

```
<doctitle>&lt;h1>=Profile Mgnt =&lt;/h1></doctitle>
<bottom>Copyright 2011. All Rights reserved></bottom>
```

(You might chose to convert `>` to `&gt;` as well, but I don't believe you have to.)

Comment: as ou suggested the build was successful however I to make a couple of changes in the <pathelement I had <b>name</b> as attribute instead of <b>path</b>.Even though the build was successful there is no change in my directory except the echo message nothing else was done as I expected, do you have anything in mind that might be a cause of failure. Thanks anyway the first question is answered. :)

Comment: My bad I figured out I had to specify every task I want to run, otherwise only the default is executed.